# errors in compiling my qt project using visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

i have a problem in my qt project. i was formerly using qt creator so all i just did was to just copy my files and create a new project in visual studio and compile. that's where the problems arose.
i am using visual studio 2010 ultimate and qt5.5.1 for msvc2010.
all plugins are loaded dynamically and qt addin for visual studio.

this is my header file

### denso_app.h

```
#ifndef DENSO_APP_H
#define DENSO_APP_H
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include "ui_denso_app.h"
class denso_app : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
denso_app(QWidget *parent = 0);
~denso_app();

private:
Ui::denso_appClass ui;
};

#endif // DENSO_APP_H
```

this is my cpp file

### denso_app.cpp

```
                #include "denso_app.h"

            denso_app::denso_app(QWidget *parent)
                : QMainWindow(parent)
            {
                ui.setupUi(this);

                QSqlDatabase mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
                mydb.setDatabaseName("C:/Users/Youniquex/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/denso_app");

                if(mydb.open())
                {
                    ui -> label_dbstat -> setText("Failed to open the database");
                }

                else
                    ui -> label_dbstat ->setText("Database Connected...");
            }

            denso_app::~denso_app()
            {

            }
```

this is my ui file.

### denso_app.ui

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>denso_appClass</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="denso_appClass">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>600</width>
        <height>400</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>denso_app</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>100</y>
          <width>411</width>
          <height>171</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>10</pointsize>
          <weight>75</weight>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>DensoApp</string>
        </property>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>150</x>
           <y>140</y>
           <width>75</width>
           <height>23</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Login</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>10</x>
           <y>30</y>
           <width>351</width>
           <height>27</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_username">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Username</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>10</x>
           <y>70</y>
           <width>351</width>
           <height>29</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_password">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Password</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>-20</y>
          <width>101</width>
          <height>101</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="pixmap">
         <pixmap>E:/DENSO/pictures/denso1.png</pixmap>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>10</y>
          <width>431</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>18</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="autoFillBackground">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;BACKGROUND:RED;&quot;&gt;DENSO MOTOR SPARES (T) LTD.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>110</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>441</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>9</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-style:italic; color:#365f91;&quot;&gt;Dealers in all types of Toyota, Nissan, Ford, Subaru, and Suzuki Genuine Parts&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_db">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>290</y>
          <width>101</width>
          <height>29</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <weight>75</weight>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Database Status:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_dbstat">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>130</x>
          <y>290</y>
          <width>251</width>
          <height>29</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <weight>75</weight>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Status</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>600</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <widget class="QMenu" name="menuDensoApp">
        <property name="title">
         <string>DensoApp</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
        <property name="title">
         <string>Help</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <addaction name="menuDensoApp"/>
       <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
       <attribute name="toolBarArea">
        <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
       </attribute>
       <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
     </widget>
     <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
     <resources>
      <include location="denso_app.qrc"/>
     </resources>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

now below are the errors i got when compiling the above project.

```
     Warning    1   warning : The name 'layoutWidget' (QWidget) is already in use, defaulting to 'layoutWidget1'.   C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.ui   1   1   denso_app
     Warning    2   warning : No resources in 'C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.qrc'. C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\RCC    denso_app
     Error  3   error C2819: type 'Ui::denso_appClass' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  1   denso_app
     Error  4   error C2232: '->Ui_denso_appClass::label_dbstat' : left operand has 'class' type, use '.'   C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  1   denso_app
     Error  5   error C2227: left of '->setText' must point to class/struct/union/generic type  C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  1   denso_app
     Error  6   error C2819: type 'Ui::denso_appClass' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  1   denso_app
     Error  7   error C2232: '->Ui_denso_appClass::label_dbstat' : left operand has 'class' type, use '.'   C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  1   denso_app
     Error  8   error C2227: left of '->setText' must point to class/struct/union/generic type  C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  1   denso_app
```

i have tried the following...
i changed the pointers and used the  * pointers in the denso_app.cpp like this

```
            if(mydb.open())
            {
                ui * label_dbstat * setText("Failed to open the database");
            }

            else
                ui * label_dbstat * setText("Database Connected...");
```

then i get the following errors again

```
    Error   1   error C2065: 'label_dbstat' : undeclared identifier C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  1   denso_app
    Error   2   error C3861: 'setText': identifier not found    C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  1   denso_app
    Error   3   error C2065: 'label_dbstat' : undeclared identifier C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  1   denso_app
    Error   4   error C3861: 'setText': identifier not found    C:\Users\Youniquex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  1   denso_app
        5   IntelliSense: identifier "label_dbstat" is undefined            c:\users\youniquex\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  8   denso_app
        6   IntelliSense: identifier "setText" is undefined c:\users\youniquex\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  13  23  denso_app
        7   IntelliSense: identifier "label_dbstat" is undefined    c:\users\youniquex\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  8   denso_app
        8   IntelliSense: identifier "setText" is undefined c:\users\youniquex\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\denso_app\denso_app\denso_app.cpp  17  23  denso_app
```

I am really stuck here and i don't really know how to get around this problem.
Please your answers are really appreciated.
Thanks and all the best.

REGARDS...

Comment: The first two "errors" are actually warnings that should be easy to understand and fix, or is there a problem?

Comment: aaaam i am not pretty sure if they are Ulrich because i have tried with my two possible options and i have failed. the problem is if i cannot get the label to inform me i my connection is connected or not how will i know that my database is connected? Please help if you can...

Comment: or @UlrichEckhardt do you know how i can go around that.. Because if i take the program and run it with qt creator i get the expected result. but i fail when i use visual studio.... please help i really need your help

Answer (score 0):

ok anyway thanks for viewing or replying to my question...
i have found the answer to my question here...
if any beginner like me comes across the same issue as me then the answer is really pretty simple as @Ulrich Eckhardt said and below is the link on how to solve the problem...

[Creating a GUI/Interface: Using Visual Studio 2010 and QT](http://mrl.cs.vsb.cz/people/davendra/UROData/Labs/Lab9b.pdf)